# Reorganizing data in R. Appending rows to columns

Tags: r, data-structures, reshape

I am facing a structure reorganization of data but unfortunately I am stuck.

I read into R let´s say a number of txt files (each has a specific name), all of them structured (data frame) in the same way with a "Gene" and 4 conditions "A1", "A2, "A3" and "A4" and their respective values:

```
Gene A1 A2 A3 A4  
Gene1 value1.1 value1.2 value1.3 value1.4
Gene2 value2.1 value2.2 value2.3 value2.4
Gene3 value3.1 value3.2 value3.3 value3.4
...
```

But each file that is read into R has a different filename (filename1, filename2, filename3,...).

I want to reorganize data from all these files into one single data file with the following structure:

```
    id Gene1_A1 Gene1_A2 Gene1_A3 Gene1_A4 Gene2_A1 Gene2_A2 Gene2_A3 Gene2_A4 Gene3_A1 Gene3_A2 Gene3_A3 Gene3_A4 ...
   filename1 value1.1 value1.2 value1.3 value1.4 value2.1 value2.2 value2.3 value2.4 value3.1 value3.2 value3.3 value3.4
    filename2
    filename3
    ...
```

In words, data from Gene2 should follow after the end of data from Gene1, then Gene3 and so on.
Each row is then representing an id (meaning every txt-filename).
Headers of the output-table is a concatenation of the "Gene"-name (Gene1, Gene2, Gene3, ...) and a condition (A1, A2, A3, A4).

Could anyone give me an advise how I could solve this?
Many thanks in advance
Kind Regards
s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sample.table.text <- "Gene A1 A2 A3 A4  
Gene1 value1.1 value1.2 value1.3 value1.4
Gene2 value2.1 value2.2 value2.3 value2.4
Gene3 value3.1 value3.2 value3.3 value3.4"

# create some sample files
files <- replicate(2, tempfile())
for (f in files) write(sample.table.text, f)

# read and reshape
dat <- lapply(files, function(fname) {
    x <- read.table(fname, header=TRUE)
    x['id'] <- basename(fname)
    reshape(x, idvar='id', timevar='Gene', direction='wide')
})
# collapse into one data.frame
result <- do.call(rbind, dat)
result
#                id A1.Gene1 A2.Gene1 A3.Gene1 A4.Gene1 A1.Gene2 A2.Gene2 A3.Gene2 A4.Gene2 A1.Gene3 A2.Gene3 A3.Gene3 A4.Gene3
# 1 file848632b4675 value1.1 value1.2 value1.3 value1.4 value2.1 value2.2 value2.3 value2.4 value3.1 value3.2 value3.3 value3.4
# 2 file84864ad4a6c value1.1 value1.2 value1.3 value1.4 value2.1 value2.2 value2.3 value2.4 value3.1 value3.2 value3.3 value3.4

# remove temp files
for (f in files) unlink(f)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, I didn´t know about this function. This is definitely doing exactly what I needed. I am trying to go through the reshape function to understand what it is exactly doing. I am also asking myself if instead of merging A1.Gene1 and so on it is also possible to merge Gene1.A1 an so on.

Comment: In this case reshape creates A1.Gene1, A2.Gene1 and so on, isn´t it possible to change the order getting Gene1.A1, Gene1.A2?

Comment: No, but try this: ` names(result) <- sapply(lapply(strsplit(names(result), '.', fixed=TRUE), rev), paste, collapse='.')`

Comment: Great, this does the job! Thanks a lot, again I learned something new